# jquery resize() not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, window

This might be very stupid, but I am not sure where I am wrong. I found jQuery 'resize()' not work at all. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FefFW/1/

`<div id="log"></div>`

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#log').append('<h3>event log</h3><hr/>');
    $('window').resize(function(){
        $('#log').append('<p>resizing...</p>');
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"window"` is not a selector; there is no `<window>` element.

You want `$(window)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $('#log').append('<h3>event log</h3><hr/>');
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('#log').append('<p>resizing...</p>');
    });
})​;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FefFW/5/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you remembered to put it within 
`$(document).ready(function() { });`
?

And yeah, like the rest just noted when watching the fiddle `'window'` is wrong.

Comment: You don't need that.  `window` always exists.